# How to display metrics in Apache Flink ui?

Tags: java, apache-flink

running Apache Flink 1.8.0. I can access the UI at `http://localhost:8081` that works. I have also verified that my job works from the IDE, submitting by command line using  `./flink run`. I have even uploaded the job through the UI. The job works fine.

But when I look at the stats on the UI, I only see a spinner. Example: Bytes Receives, Records Received, Bytes Sent, Records Sent all have a spinner.

Also I'm doing in my `RichAsyncFunction`

It's not clear in the docs for the UI, do we need to enable something on the Flink server?

```java
private transient Counter lookupCounter;
@Override
public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
    super.open(parameters);

    this.lookupCounter = getRuntimeContext()
            .getMetricGroup()
            .addGroup("MyGroup")
            .counter("myCounter");
}

@Override
public void asyncInvoke(String input, ResultFuture<Map<String, Integer>> resultFuture) throws Exception {
    lookupCounter.inc();
}
```

Also clicking on Task metrics I get nothing. I can't click the `Add metric` button.

Comment: Maybe the answer to my question is helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60490957/apache-flink-dashboard-not-showing-metrics

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem ... but I ran flink in a docker swarm.

In flink-config file, I used the host name for the task managers name. If change I it and use the flink random names for the task managers, the metrics appear again.

In other hand, I read that you may be sure that not use "detached mode" at run, because the metrics are not available in detached mode.

I hope that helps